# How to write a function that filters numbers if they lie within a range

Tags: python, list, lambda

I want to write a function `inRange`, that should return a list containing all, and only, the elements of `l` whose values are between low and high inclusive. For example, `inRange(3, 10, [2, 3, 7, 17, 10, 7, -9])` returns `[3, 7, 10, 7]`. I can only do this function using map, filter, reduce, list, lambda.

This is my current code which does not work:

```py
def inRange(lo, hi, l):
    return list(filter(lambda lo, hi, l: l in range(lo, hi))

print(inRange(10, 20, [10, 14, 16, 17, 20, 21, 23, 12]))
```

Comment: `return list(filter(lambda n: low < n < hi, l))`

Comment: @joshmeranda Thank you, there was only one mistake and it was that it was not returning the 3 or 10, but I fixed it with `<=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for this function:

```py
def inRange(lo, hi, l):
     return list(filter(lambda i: lo <= i <= hi, l))

print(inRange(10, 20, [10, 14, 16, 17, 20, 21, 23, 12]))
```

Output:

```
[10, 14, 16, 17, 20, 12]
```

Reference:

- [filter() in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/filter-in-python/)